# Yii2 Basic Hide Model Name in form field

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In my form, in Yii2 Basic if I try to inspect element for the field I get the name of model and table row

example

```
<input id="userlogin-username" class="form-control" name="Userlogin[Username]" maxlength="30" aria-required="true" type="text">
```

`name=` is showing the model name : `Userlogin`, and table row is `Username`. Is it possible to hide the name of the model and the table row like for example, `name="user"` instead of `name="Userlogin[Username]"`.

Is it possible or it's impossible.

Thank you

Comment: They are used in a specific way because when you call the `$model->load()` after posting the form it will load the array of the model named `UserLogin` i won't recommend you do this but why are you going for this any reason, can you explain? maybe we can come up with some better solution

Comment: I'm creating a web so for security I won't users know the models name and tables row

Comment: haha dont worry its not that easy to do any thing even if they know the model name.

Comment: is it possible to change it or it's impossible

Comment: Neary anything is _possible_, what's _practical_ is more up to your situation. What have you tried? You can define additional properties in your model (like `user`) and/or pass different fields to your authentication (like `email` e.g.), it really depends on your app and the cost/benefit in maintenance. As @MuhammadOmerAslam mentions, it's unlikely that someone knowing the schema is going to compromise your security, and if so, you have bigger problems. The form itself is going to be the primary attack vector.

Comment: i would say **yes it is** just like `YII` pronounces and **an answer below already mentions that**, but again as @Idg also said you should add proper detail i wont recommend wasting your efforts and time on something that is not needed if you are concerned about the table names why dont you use prefix for tables in the `config` for the database connection no one will be able to guess your table's actual name as the model name does not include the prefix and it takes less effort to prevent the same thing you are trying to do the long way

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the name of the model by implementing "formName" in your model: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName()-detail

Answer (score 0):

If you go by the Yii way, you should set and pass data by using the model. Now to do what you need (security by obscurity) you will end or doing a model less form or using `DynamicModel`.

To do this you will have to do a lot of extra work on the Controller to read fields.

Op1: Form by hand
This is also a lot of work, and you will end having forms disconnected from yii.
Make a form by hand like

```
<form method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now in your Controller read the fields by using `$request->post()` and then load them by hand to the model.

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;
$post = $request->post();
$model = new User();
$model->username = $post['username'];
```

Op2: `DynamicModel`  way.
When entering the controller o by making a dumb model, use `DynamicModel` to set the fields.

Then when using `$model->load()` you will be loading the `DynamicModel`, when loaded you will have to load by hand the fields like `$userModel->usewr_name = $dModel->user_name`

Now your forms will show `DynamicModel[user_name]`.
With this you can hide your models.

Build you [DynamicModel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-dynamicmodel.html) like:

```
public function actionForm()
{
    $model = DynamicModel::validateData(compact('username'), [
        [['username'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
        ['username'],
    ]);
    if ($model->hasErrors()) {
        // validation fails
    } else {
        // validation succeeds
    }
}
```

I don't say this is the best way, it's a way to do what you need. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = isset($options['name']) ? $options['name'] : static::getInputName($model, $attribute);
```

The above line from yii/helpers/BaseHtml::activeInput() is used to generate field name for model fields. So, it is safe to assume that setting name of field in options will remove model name entirely from the field names. [Warning: I have never tried it. This is just from my limited understanding of the code] Example:

```
$form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['name' => 'myusername']);
```

However, this will create more problems than solve some. Model::load() uses the model's form name to populate attributes based on scenario and rule settings (read about safe attributes for details). This means that you will have to remember to load all fields from your request to your model in controller action, which is not friendly in the long run when the model evolves. So, a better solution is to override Model::formName() method

```
public function formName() {
    return 'myUser';
}
```

This will result in names such as `myUser[Username]`.

There are other options like creating a Model to act as form with your choice of form name and field names and copy values on submit to your current model, but that is not usually necessary.